# Ruby Spreadsheet Gem: extracting value from a formula cell in an Excel file

Tags: ruby, excel

I'm using the spreadsheet gem for an RoR app.

I'm extracting data from a cell in the Excel sheet using the following line of code:

```
current_qsubnum = @mainsheet.cell(y_qsubnum, x_current)
```

I then do some processing based on this data.

However, what I've realized is that sometimes my users put a formula in that cell, which I can't process. I need to grab the value from the cell, rather than the formula.

However, whenever I apply the value method, it still is getting me the formula.  I've tried this:

```
current_qsubnum = @mainsheet.cell(y_qsubnum, x_current).value
```

And this:

```
current_qsubnum = @mainsheet[y_qsubnum, x_current].value
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: why you are not using win32ole link?

Comment: The app is meant to be offered up online as a web service. My understanding of win32ole is that the user would have to run it locally on their machine. Or is my understanding incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

while looping in to the Excel sheet you can check for class of cell.

`worksheet.each do |row|
   row_value = row[n].value if row[n].is_a?(Spreadsheet::Formula)#get value from formula cell
end`